# Google Play Leaderboard UI Color Change

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard, achievements

In the game I just developed, the Leaderboard UI color was dark translucent green until a week ago. This was feel-good looking(at least non-irritant to eyes). All of a sudden it changed to bright translucent red and is staying in that color since then. This color in no way matches with any screen at any stage of my game. This is the state of my Leaderboard screen now:

[image: Leaderboard Screenshot]

This is much worse in the phone screen with translucent effect. Here I've reduced the transparency of the screenshot to blur the background. This is the same case with Achievements UI too.

So my questions are

1. How Google decides what color an app's Leaderboard UI should have?
2. Can I specify the color of my app's Leaderboard/Achevements UI?

I don't want to do any change anything except the eye-piercing bright color of the UI to a normal darker tone. Anyone please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play games uses the new Palette api to find a key color from your application icon for that background. I think the only way to change it is to change your app icon. For my apps, one is purple and the other is a light tan color.

Comment: My icon doesn't have a single red pixel but the leaderboard ui is read :/

Answer (score 1):

This color is actually based on the Featured Image of your game. The icon is irrelevant. Changing the featured image will change what color is associated with your game UI.

Comment: any idea how long does it take to update after you change the feature graphic?