# Open the play games leaderboards intent in dark mode

Tags: android, google-play-games

Is there any way to open the play games leaderboards intent in dark mode?

Comment: What is the name of the games leaderboards activity? Could you set a breakpoint in `startActivityForResult(intent, RC_LEADERBOARD_UI);` and inspect that? Then we could inspect the source code for Android to see if there is an option for darkmode.

Comment: I didn't found an option to enable dark mode

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28077524/13772418), the color of the leaderboard intent is set <s>randomly</s> by the images you use when uploading your app.

If you want full control on the UI, [you can get the raw data from the leaderboard](https://truizlop.github.io/development/how-to-create-custom-achievements-leaderboards-android/) and display in a custom layout.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to force darkmode:

> Apps must opt-in to Force Dark by setting `android:forceDarkAllowed="true"` in the activity's theme. This attribute is set on all of the system and AndroidX provided light themes, such as `Theme.Material.Light`. When you use Force Dark, you should make sure to test your app thoroughly and exclude views as needed.

More [information is found here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#force_dark).

Comment: It doesn't work on play games leaderboard activity :(

Comment: if you find the name to the activity we could then search the Android source code to see how it is implemented and figure out how to force it to black. From here: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject

Comment: com.google.android.play.games/com.google.android.gms.games.ui.clientv2.leaderboards.LeaderboardActivity

Comment: Will look into it, I'll get back.